# Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, adobe-edge

I am trying to create a display banner that scrolls with the hosting page, see example ...
[3. Cut Out MPU](http://next.theguardian.com/blog/responsive-takeover)

I have used Edge Animate to build, and Javascript to program the functionality (or tried at least), the banner is 300x250 px, and the image is around 700px, this image animates from top (0px) to bottom (700px) over 4 secs in the timeline.

The Javascript I am using was figured out and kindly uploaded [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/29/syncing-edge-animate-with-window-scroll)

Amount user can scroll = 100% / animation length = 100% 
Amount user has scrolled = 10% / timeline position = 10%

This should all be working correctly, however when I preview the edge animate composition in a browser (Chrome), console log shows...

> Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element

When I add this composition to a test web page with some phoney content, I get the same error as above as well as this error when I scroll...

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
> getScrollPerc
> window.onscroll

The Javascript is firing as the error tally counts up as I scroll, but I cannot figure out how I have made an error in my code. My code from Edge is below...

```
(function($, Edge, compId){
var Composition = Edge.Composition, Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for commonly used Edge classes

   //Edge symbol: 'stage'
   (function(symbolName) {
    



      Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "document", "compositionReady", function(sym, e) {
         
         // insert code to be run when the composition is fully loaded here
         var animSize = getDuration();
         window.onscroll = function(e) {
           var perc = getScrollPerc();
           var animPos = (perc/100) * animSize;
           sym.stop(animPos);
         }
          
         function getScrollPerc() {
           var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
           return (wintop/(docheight-winheight))*100;
         }
          
         if(getScrollPerc() > 0) {
           console.log('do initial move');
           var perc = getScrollPerc();
           var animPos = (perc/100) * animSize;
           setTimeout(function() { sym.stop(animPos);}, 0);
         }

      });
      //Edge binding end

   })("stage");
   //Edge symbol end:'stage'

})(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-4414348");
```

I have tried a fix found on Adobe forums (not enough rep to link) which states that these functions are only available within `compositionReady` as it is a local function, and by adding the sym. prefix, they will be available. I have however not been able to rectify my error.

Any information or help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same issue here. I tried to pull in json from external server. my ajax code works fine in a test.html file as a standalone script, but in edge xxxAction.js environment doesn't...